# Best practices for deploying ASP.NET Core components across multiple VMs

Tags: docker, virtual-machines, deployment, dotnet-framework

I'm working on a project that requires deployment both on the **cloud** and on **private virtual machines**. The customer provided 4 VMs with the stipulation that the database should be on one VM, the application on others, and certain services on specific VMs.

**Specifics: Single ASP.NET Core Project:**

Can I achieve this deployment structure with a **single ASP.NET Core Aspire project**, or do I need different APP HOSTS with connections to Docker containers on different VMs?

**Deployment Recommendations:**

What are the best practices for deploying different components of a system on separate VMs while ensuring efficient communication and maintainability?

**Docker Containerization:**

Should I consider containerizing services and applications for streamlined deployment across different VMs?

**Database Management:**

Any suggestions on managing a database on a separate VM while maintaining smooth interactions with the application?

If I am wrong about any concept please feel free to correct it.
I want all my services to be deployed on dockers over Windows Server.

Comment: `If I am wrong about any concept please feel free to correct it. I want all my services to be deployed on dockers over Windows Server 2012` Windows Server 2012 is end of life and off topic on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, stay away from docker windows containers, they are a pain in the ass.

You are saying you need to deploy ASP.net components on a couple of VM in the private network and in the cloud.
I think you first need to look at your architecture. Do i need a front-end, do i need a back-end. Do the asp.net components have dependencies on server roles we need to install, for example IIS. Which server is going to have which role and components?

Regarding this question
*Deployment Recommendations:
What are the best practices for deploying different components of a system on separate VMs while ensuring efficient communication and maintainability?*

Best practices are in my opinion:

- Use a naming convention and deploy all everything on the servers in
  the same way as much possible (for example logfiles on a seperate
  drive, and that the same on each server)
  -Use least privilege, grant service accounts and so, the permissions the only need and as less possible. Document that
- only open network ports when required, and keep it as minimal as possible. Document that
- Do a sizing with the customer and check if the servers have enough resources.
- Harden the servers, for example with a cis benchmark to keep the attack surface as low as possible.
- Install all the latest updates and patches.